# How to use Optima font in Overleaf with any compiler?

Tags: xetex, tex-core, overleaf

I'm a new LaTeX user with my first use case being math proofs.

I want to use Optima font (which came installed on my Mac) for my proof, and as far as I can tell I have to use the XeLaTeX compiler to use a custom font like this. I uploaded the Optima.ttc file to Overleaf and it worked somewhat - only the regular style is used. There is no bold or italics. I either want to

1. Get the font working in all of its styles, or
2. Use Optima as my body paragraph text only and use another font that can be bolded or italicized for titles and everything else.

Here's what I have going on at the top of my file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont {[Optima.ttc]}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

From [the `fontspec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf):

> ## 4 Selecting fonts from TrueType Collections (TTC files)
>
> TrueType Collections are multiple fonts contained within a single
>   file. Each font within a collection must be explicitly chosen using
>   the `FontIndex` command. Since TrueType Collections are often used to
>   contain the italic/bold shapes in a family, `fontspec` automatically
>   selects the italic, bold, and bold italic fontfaces from the same
>   file. For example, to load the macOS system font Optima:
>
> ```
> \setmainfont{Optima.ttc}[
>   Path = /System/Library/Fonts/ ,
>   UprightFeatures = {FontIndex=0} ,
>   BoldFeatures = {FontIndex=1} ,
>   ItalicFeatures = {FontIndex=2} ,
>   BoldItalicFeatures = {FontIndex=3} ,
> ]
> ```
>
> Support for TrueType Collections has only been tested in XeTeX, but
>   should also work with an up-to-date version of LuaTEX and the
>   `luaotfload` package.

Since you have uploaded the file to the same directory as your main TeX file in Overleaf, you shouldn't need the `Path` parameter.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I will refer to that manual if I run into any more problems like this, just wasn't sure where to look.Thank you so much!